# How can I make list item with uniform length?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am creating an unordered list for horizontal tab component. I want each list item filling in one of three boxes with uniform length and height shown on the image. Here is my jsFiddle and javascript. What should I change on CSS to make this happen?

[image: na.cx/i/a7J56X.png]

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1xhc4v5/6/).

Comment: Pls set the image for better understanding your problem. Thanks.

Comment: na.cx/i/a7J56X.png  this is the link to the image. I'll try to upload it to stackoverflow but I failed yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML & CSS: How to create four equal size tabs that fill 100% width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019386/html-css-how-to-create-four-equal-size-tabs-that-fill-100-width)

I tried table display yesterday but did not work yesterday. Yet, it seems to work today so I post it in case someone shares the same problem with me

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution.

One of advices and solutions is also to take look on [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) components, and just include the classes correctly:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
 <body>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li role="" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role=""><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role=""><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

I think this can also be helpful, you can save a lot of time with design :)